# Prevent WordPress search from search a specific pages parentpages

Tags: wordpress, search

I have a certain page in WordPress that have parent pages. I want to exclude those parent pages from WordPress search.

In functions.php I have tried this:

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
if ($query->is_search) {
$query->set('post_parent', '4');
}
return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

Well with this code only the post_parent is searchable, but I want the opposite. How would this look like?

UPDATE: Problem solved. Here's the solution (4 is the ID of the specific page where parent pages is to be excluded from search):

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_parent__not_in', array(4));
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

Kind regards
Johan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Wordpress 3.6, can use new query param: [`post_parent__not_in`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)

`post_parent__not_in (array) - use post ids. Specify posts whose parent is not in an array.`

Answer (score 0):

**Use This code function in your Theme's function.php file with page id which is you want to exclude from your Theme's  custom search bar...And Enjoy with it...!**

```
// Exclude specific posts/pages from search
function exclude_pages_from_search($query) {    

   if ( $query->is_main_query() && is_search() ) { 

         $exclude_ids = array(11);// Array of the ID's to exclude   
         $query->set( 'post__not_in', $exclude_ids );   
        }   
           return $query; 
     } 

add_filter('pre_get_posts','exclude_pages_from_search' );
```